# Convert the URL entered by user in textbox to URI format

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone application. The user enters the ip and port of his server, database name, username and password.
In the code i access the url entered by 'urltext.Text' But the error pops up 'Invalid URI format'. How to convert the data from textbox to valid URI format.

```
private void SendDataButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri myuri = new Uri(urltext.Text);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myuri);
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello I m here");
        Debug.WriteLine(request.GetType());
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), request);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image]

I want to take that entered url from the user and put in .Create()
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myuri);

Comment: What is the data entered? not every string can be converted to a URI...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If the format is correct, then you can use it. If the format is incorrect, then, in general, there's no way to convert it into a correct format. What format strings ae you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
Uri myuri = new Uri(urltext.Text);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myuri);
```

instead of

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urltext.Text);
```

hope it work for you

Comment: What if the user enters an invalid uri? inputs like `htp:/32.34:8032`, or `htt://12.32.423.12:80` or even `my url is none of your business` will cause  an exception. **Never** trust the user input.

Comment: The code in the question already says that so I don't see how this is even an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should always verify the user input.
In that case, you can use the static method [`IsWellFormedUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to check the input string:

```
if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(Input, UriKind.Absolute)) 
{
    Uri MyUri = new Uri(Input);     
    // Do your stuff
}
else
{
   // Alert the client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CheckHostName static method of the Uri class to validate the text. This can be an IPv4 or IPv6 address or an Internet host name.

> Uri.CheckHostName

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx